# Questions on the behaviour of functions of exponential type 1

Tags: cv.complex-variables, growth-rate

I am interested in understanding the properties of entire functions of exponential type 1. I have few questions about their growth.

How many sectors can a function of exponential type have, in which its modulus increases exponentially? Do zeros have to stay away from such sectors?

If we restrict the exponential type to 1, does the answer to the above question change?

I was looking into the Weierstrass factorization of entire functions from which we get (assuming that I didn't misunderstand anything) that if $f$ is of exponential type and $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$ is the set of its zeros, then we have 2 cases:

either
$$ f(z) = M z^m e^{b z} \prod_{a_i\in A} \Big(1-\tfrac{z}{a_i}\Big) e^{\frac{z}{a_i}} $$ for some $M$, $b\in\mathbb{C}$
and $ \sum_{a_i\in A} a_i^{-2} <\infty$,

or 
$$ f(z) = M z^m \prod_{a_i\in A} \Big(1-\tfrac{z}{a_i}\Big) $$ for some $M\in\mathbb{C}$ and $ \sum_{a_i\in A} a_i^{-1} <\infty$.

Am I correct with this? Are both cases valid?

What can we say more if we further assume that the exponential type is 1? Does it mean that $|b|\le 1$, for example?

How can one majorate products of the form $$ \prod_{a_i\in A} \Big(1-\tfrac{z^2}{a_i^2}\Big) $$ with $ \sum_{a_i\in A} a_i^{-2} <\infty$,
or products of the form $$ \prod_{a_i\in A} \Big(1-\tfrac{z}{a_i}\Big) $$
with $ \sum_{a_i\in A} a_i^{-2} <\infty$? Is there a standard machinery for that?
If they are infinite, what kind of entire functions these products define? Are there of order 1? If yes, what can be said about their type?

Comment: You should state your question precisely: what do you mean by "sectors where modulus increases exponentially" ?

Comment: I mean sectors where if the majorant is a convex function, then it has to increase at least exponentially.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I forgot to tag you in my comment and I didn't know if you would see it.

Comment: Perhaps what you're asking about is the *indicator function* $h(\theta)=\limsup \log|f(Re^{i\theta})|/R$. The standard books (Boas, for example) have material on this.

Comment: @ChristianRemling not really. What I am interested in is to describe all functions of exponential 1 that decay exponentially along the positive real axis. So ultimately I would like to know if I can tell whether this happens by looking at the Weierstrass factorization.

Comment: @tst: please state your question PRECISELY, using complete quantified mathematical sentences, do not make us guess what you mean, if you really want an answer.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko as I said above I am want to describe the space of functions of exponential type that decay exponentially along the positive real axis. I don't expect that anyone knows that so I wrote a bunch of related questions. I will be happy even with a partial answer to any of them.